# Time in milliseconds without seconds

Tags: python

I want to have the current time without the seconds.
I use this: `int(round(time.time() * 1000))` to get the current time, I get this as result:`1589835912648`
But when I transform (using `datetime.fromtimestamp(int(1589835912648/1000))` ) it to something readable, I get this: `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 18, 23, 5, 12)`

which is normal. But I want to get rid of the seconds!

like `datetime.fromtimestamp(int(1589746140000/1000))` which gives: `datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 17, 22, 9)`
So, it gives the time without the seconds.

How can I do this?

I already tried `round(int(round(time.time() * 1000)),-4)` but that also gives me the seconds

Hope this is clear and that someone can help me

Comment: In fact, I want the milliseconds part (like 1589746140000) which doesn't give me the seconds. Now I get always a result which contains seconds. So, How can I get the milliseconds part without seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with using something other than datetime, here:

```py
import time
print(time.strftime("%H:%m"))
```

This will print the time in hours and minutes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, you can read more about strftime [here](https://strftime.org/).

Answer (score 0):

`datetime.datetime` is good for this because you can access each field easily by name:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.hour, now.minute
(14, 17)
```

or you can turn it into a string with `strftime`:

```
>>> datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M")
'14:17'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

current_time = datetime.now()

hour = current_time.hour
minute = current_time.minute

print(f"{hour}:{minute}")
```

Comment: This simply returns the time you would see on a digital clock